# OSX -bash: composer: command not found

Tags: macos, composer-php

If i type "composer" i get the above error message.

I did on my macbook:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

to install Composer globally.

I had to manually create the /local/bin/composer directory, maybe this caused the error ?

```
php composer.phar
```

works if i in my code directory where the .phar file is.

What could i do to solve the problem and run composer globally ?

My ~/.profile

```
export PS1="\W: "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
```

~: echo $PATH

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
~:
```

Comment: `chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/composer` and add `/usr/local/bin` to `$PATH` in `~/.bash_profile`.  This is basic user stuff and does not belong here.

Comment: What exactly should i add to my .profile ?
I updated my post with the content of my .profile

Comment: So composer is now at `/usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar`?

Comment: Same problem on mac os x 10.11.4 here with `/usr/local/bin` & `/usr/local/bin/composer` in the $PATH, still getting `-bash: /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar: Permission denied`

Comment: @Pmpr Have you got any solution for permissions issue?

Comment: @AshwaniGarg Sorry, but dont remember that anymore.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

The path `/usr/local/bin/composer` is not in your PATH, executables in that folder won't be found.

Delete the folder `/usr/local/bin/composer`, then run

```
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

This moves `composer.phar` into `/usr/local/bin/` and renames it into `composer` (which is still an executable, not a folder).

Then just use it like:

```
$ composer ...
```

Comment: The fact that you're typing in "$" perhaps? That's just to signify your command line prompt, which typically is "$".

Comment: I'm getting a `composer: Permission denied`  saw some solutions with `sudo chmod`  but i'm getting `sudo: not found`    (it's a synology (busybox))

Comment: Maybe that is why `$` should not be included in answers. Seems obvious to us but not to new people. And it is also obvious that you don't need the `$` for people to understand that you are talking about the terminal.

Comment: I think including the $ is great (if you have problems understanding what the $ is for hmmm then maybe linux scripting is not for you?)

Comment: Why is this not in the documentation on composer! Ty @deceze

Comment: @Jonas The Composer documentation doesn't advise creating any folders, and if you just follow exactly what it says, you won't see this problem at all: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Comment: After digging around. This is the only way that works for me on the mac.

Comment: Yeah this works. you need to delete "composer" folder at the end of this path `/usr/local/bin/composer` then run the command `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: It's helpful to have the $ in stack overflow answers to signify the beginning of the command line.

Answer (score 95):

Well I tried a lot of things but none seemed to be working. But the following process did it right, I can now use `composer` command in terminal. I'm in mac OS 10.12.1

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ chmod +x composer.phar
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ composer
```

Comment: I tried this on MacOS M1, working like charm and saved my lot of time. Thanks for the solution

Comment: zsh: permission denied: composer

Comment: Works perfect on MacOS Monterey. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

I get into the same issue even after moving the `composer.phar` to '/usr/local/bin/composer' using the following command in amazon linux.

`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

I used the following command to create a alias for the composer file. So now its running globally.

**`alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'`**

I don't know whether this will work in OS-X. But when i search with this issue i get this link. So I'm just posting here. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Yea it worked after creating alias.
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'

Comment: Great article! I have been searched a lot for this.

Answer (score 24):

Tested on Mac OSX after installing via instructions on composer website:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 11):

This works on Ubuntu;

```
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar'
```

Comment: you should restart your terminal once you had done this

Comment: @lone_coder you made my day, in fact I was stuck, and the solution was as simple as just restarting the terminal

Answer (score 10):

Globally install Composer on OS X 10.11 El Capitan

This command will NOT work in OS X 10.11:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

Instead, let's write to the /usr/local/bin path for the user:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Now we can access the composer command globally, just like before.

Comment: I get php: command not found

Answer (score 4):

this wasted me a day or two. like why dont anybody say on tutorials that the command composer is not to be used without actually linking and stuff... I mean everyone is writing composer command like its the next step when we are not all 5 years experienced  users to know these details.

`cp composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

did it for me on ubuntu after getting stuck for 2 days

Comment: Me too, followed all the tutorials and they couldn't add one tiny line or two of information about the command being moved to /usr/local/bin/composer. They all say to run something like run "export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"" and it does not fix it!

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for me this time in the permissions issue.

```
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, for anyone having:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied

problem, while trying to move downloaded `composer.phar` using:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

this is the cause:

**System Integrity Protection**

and this is the solution:

1. Reboot in recovery mode: restart you mac and hold down **cmd+R**.
2. Open the terminal once recovery mode has started via **Utilities>Terminal** via the bar at the top.
3. Type in `csrutil disable` and hit enter. You should see a msg returned saying that:

   > the System Integrity Protection is off.
4. Restart the computer as normal and then go set up composer. I had to put it in `/usr/bin` and **NOT** `/usr/local/bin` because for some reason it just didn't work there.
5. Go back to recovery mode and enable System Integrity Protector by typing `csrutil enable`
6. Come back in normal boot up and check that composer works. It did for me.

The above 6 steps are copied from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/trouble-installing-composer-believe-it-or-not?page=0#reply-104035), so all the credit belongs to the user **Vasheer** there.

Comment: You should chmod +x the binary instead of just turning off your csrutil ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have to run **composer** with **sudo**, you should change the directory of **composer** to

```
/usr/bin
```

this was tested on Centos8.

Answer (score 0):

Composer is avialble and install the packages in the global path but they are not available in the shell, Mac in my case. I managed to fix this by adding the global bin to the path at my bash file.

Steps:

First, check what is your home directory by typing in the shell:

```
cd ~
pwd
```

this will tell you the home path

The next step is to verify that composer set the global directory there:

```
ls -al .composer
```

If you got list of files that's mean composer set up the directory, if not - look above or in the documentation.

The next step is to edit the bash profile. Mine is ~/.bash_profile but other can ~/.zshrc. If you don't have any one like this try to see how to set up aliases and place the the code in aliases file:

```
PATH="YOUR_HOME_PATH/.composer/vendor/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

That's it! just reload the file with

```
source PATH_TO_FILE
```

And you good to go!